# Display JSON in div with jQuery Mobile each time a page is shown

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to get my jQuery Mobile app to display information about a photo album if a user is logged in and connected to one. I am using $.ajax to post to my server and grab the data. When the app opens the correct data is displayed on the home page but when I navigate to the other page where it is supposed to be displayed the div is empty, even though I know the data is being retrieved. It's almost like the div is not being injected properly. Below is my home page and also the upload page.

Home Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Wedding Connect</title>
    <link href="css/jquery-mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/application.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="js/application.js">script> -->
    <script src="js/jquery-mobile.js"></script>
    <script src="js/cordova.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="home" data-title="Home" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Back">

    <!-- header -->
    <div id="header" data-role="header"><p align="center">Welcome to Wedding Connect</p></div>
    <!-- /header -->

    <!-- content -->
    <div id="content" data-role="content">
        <div id="album-info"></div>
        <nav>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
                <li><a href="login.html" data-transition="slide">Enter Album Code</a></li>
                <li><a href="upload.html" data-transition="slide">Upload a Photo</a></li>
                <li><a href="instructions.html" data-transition="slide">Instructions</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- /content -->

    <!-- footer -->
    <div id="footer" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <nav data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="home.html" data-transition="slide" data-icon="home" data-theme="b">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="upload.html" data-transition="slide" data-icon="plus" data-theme="b">Upload Photo</a></li>
                <li><a href="update.html" data-transition="slide" data-icon="gear" data-theme="b">New Album</a></li>
                <li><a href="instructions.html" data-transition="slide" data-icon="info" data-theme="b">Instructions</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- /footer -->

    <script>
    $("#home").on('pageshow', function () {
        // For testing purposes only
        localStorage.setItem('album_code', '1234');
        var album_code = localStorage.getItem('album_code');
        if (album_code !== null) {
            // Attempt to authenticate the album code
            $.ajax({  
                url: "http://localhost/weddingconnect/index.php/mobile/verify",
                type: "post",  
                data: {album_code: album_code},
                dataType: 'json',
                crossDomain: true,
                error:function() {
                    alert('Server communication error. Could not validate stored album code.');
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.response == "TRUE") {
                        // Retrieve album information
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "http://localhost/weddingconnect/index.php/mobile/get-album",
                            type: "post",
                            data: {album_code: album_code},
                            dataType: 'json',
                            crossDomain: true,
                            error: function() {
                                alert('Server communication error. Could not retrieve album information.');
                            },
                            success: function(data) {
                                if (data.response == "TRUE") {
                                    $('#album-info').html(
                                        '<p align="center"><strong>Album:</strong> ' + 
                                        data.album + ' <strong>By:</strong> ' + 
                                        data.bride + ' & ' + 
                                        data.groom + '</p>'
                                    );
                                } else {
                                    $('#album-info').html('<p align="center">Error retrieving album information.</p>');
                                }
                            }
                        });                 
                    } else {
                        localStorage.removeItem('album_code');
                        $('#album-info').html('<p align="center">You are not connected to an album at this time.</p>');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
    </script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Upload Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Wedding Connect</title>
    <link href="css/jquery-mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/application.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="js/application.js">script> -->
    <script src="js/jquery-mobile.js"></script>
    <script src="js/cordova.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="upload" data-title="Upload" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Back">

    <div data-role="header"><p align="center">Welcome to Wedding Connect</p></div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="album-info"></div>
        <script src="js/upload.js"></script>
        <input type="hidden" id="serverUrl" value="http://localhost/weddingconnect/mobile/upload" />
        <input type="button" onclick="capturePhoto();" value="Take Picture" />
        <input type="button" onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);" value="Select Picture" />
        <input type="button" onclick="uploadPhoto();" value="Upload" data-theme="b" />
        <img id="smallImage" src="" />
        <img id="largeImage" src="" />
    </div>

    <div id="footer" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <nav data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="home.html" data-transition="slide" data-icon="home" data-theme="b">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="upload.html" data-transition="slide" data-icon="plus" data-theme="b">Upload Photo</a></li>
                <li><a href="update.html" data-transition="slide" data-icon="gear" data-theme="b">New Album</a></li>
                <li><a href="instructions.html" data-transition="slide" data-icon="info" data-theme="b">Instructions</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <script>
    $("#upload").on("pageshow", function() {
        //alert('upload');
        var album_code = localStorage.getItem('album_code');
        //alert(album_code);

        // If no album code is present send the user to the login page
        if (album_code === null) {
            $.mobile.changePage("login.html", {
                transition: "slide"
            });
        }
        // Retrieve the album information
        $.ajax({  
            url: "http://localhost/weddingconnect/index.php/mobile/get-album",
            type: "post",  
            data: {album_code: album_code},
            dataType: 'json',
            crossDomain: true,
            error:function() {
                alert('Server communication error. Could not retrieve album information.');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.response == "TRUE") {
                    alert(data.groom);
                    $('#album-info').html(
                        '<p align="center"><strong>Album:</strong> ' + 
                        data.album + ' <strong>By:</strong> ' + 
                        data.bride + ' & ' + 
                        data.groom + '</p>'
                    );
                } else {
                    $('#album-info').html('<p align="center">Error retrieving album information.</p>');
                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I feel like it's something simple that I am missing. I know you can't use $(document).ready(function(){  with jQM so I am using pagebeforeshow for each page. How do I get this to properly display each time a page is shown? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the $("#upload").on("pagebeforeshow") getting called ?

Comment: No it wasn't. I tried to alert the album_code and got nothing so I changed all of the pagebeforeshow to pageshow. After that the alert showed the right content. I then put another alert right above where  trying to append the data to the div. That alert box shows the proper data but it does not append to the div. I don't understand.

Comment: could you please show your HTML's

Comment: Sure, how can I put code into a comment?

Comment: you can edit the question and update it with the code.

Comment: When I re-tested the edits I made, everything worked.